# "Control" Property In Custom Renderers and Effects Is Null For Layouts

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I try to write a custom renderer for any of the layout classes, the "Control" property appears null. It is OK since the renderer already is the wrapper for the native control but it is a problem when creating an Effect. So I cannot do any customization with the layout classes using Effects since Control property is not assigned. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7):

The `PlatformEffect` class has another property called `Container` which could also be used for the effect when the `Control` is null, e.g. at layouts.

Answer (score 0):

So I saw the same issue as the original post.

I was inheriting `PlatformEffect<UIView, UILabel>` on iOS.  The control was null when I was debugging.  I changed my Effect to inherit from `PlatformEffect` and then cast the control as `((UILabel)Control)` and everything started working.

**Returned a Null Control**

```
MultilineTruncateLabelEffect : PlatformEffect<UIView, UILabel>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var effect = (MultilineEffect) Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is MultilineEffect);
            if (effect != null)
            {
                Control.Lines = effect.Lines;
            }
    }
}
```

**Worked Fine**

```
public class MultilineTruncateLabelEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var effect = (MultilineEffect) Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is MultilineEffect);
        if (effect != null)
        {
            ((UILabel)Control).Lines = effect.Lines;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Layout do not have renderers, and as they have no renderers or native views (i.e. no `Control`), there's nothing you could possibly modify with an `Effect`.

Comment: According to this link, they have: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/renderers/. They are View derivatives in Android and UIView derivatives in iOS.

Comment: They "kind of have". For example I am using custom renderer for BoxView. I have access from the renderer "Element.ViewGroup" as specified in the table. But "Control" is null.